# Tacking "Stack Exchange" on to the names of some sites breaks stuff

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, profile-page

Recently, "Stack Exchange" was added to the names of certain sites (the ones without special names). This shows up in [profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEdpz.png), [mobile site headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Dv3.png), and [site `<title>`s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVTC3.png).

However, some site names are breaking things:

[image]

(My account on the same site shows up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6N43.png), since my top 5 have relatively short names. This is what it used to look like)

And:

[image]

This is happening for all users who have one of the sites with long names in their top 5 on all of their profiles network wide.

Could this be fixed? As it is it seems redundant to tack "Stack Exchange" on to all these site names.

Comment: Another 1st April from SE?

Comment: This was my bug that was masked by caching; a fix will be pushed out soon.

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Ah, OK. I was afraid that it was a feature :S. Thanks!

Comment: @Aditya: No, they're still there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has been fixed and deployed - let me know if you see any other instances of this happening, please!

Comment: Page `<title>`s and the headline of mobile sites still have this. It's not breaking anything, but just wanted to check if it's intentional :)

Comment: So the whole "Stack Exchange" addition was a mistake to begin with??

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd we did a refactoring of how our sites' names were stored in the DB and how they were accessed from the code.  For SE 2.0 sites, we wanted "Stack Exchange" to be visible in almost all places the name is shown, exceptions being the logo and any extremely space-constrained usage.  Sites that have vanity names, e.g. Ask Ubuntu, Seasoned Advice, aren't affected.

Comment: @Manishearth Removing the "Stack Exchange" from mobile's header in the next build, thanks.

Comment: Oh, one more place, magic links. [scifi.se] [sqa.se] [money.se] (chat seems fine, though)

Comment: @Manishearth will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Still seeing this problem on mobile

Comment: @JarrodDixon This is also still happening in the auto-fill for migrating questions, which causes all sites with "Stack Exchange" appended to appear *after* their meta site in the list. "Stack Excahnge" is also inserted into the `[chat]` magic comment link.

Comment: @Jim should be fixed now, thanks for finding that.

Comment: @JarrodDixon still shows up on mobile. Causes the site names to wrap to new lines.

Comment: @Jim where is this happening?

Comment: @JarrodDixon on the profile page

Comment: @Jim doh, my bad - I had forgotten there were mobile versions of our user page's panels.  Will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: @JarrodDixon I'm not sure if this is intentional, but the `<title>` on metas is a bit weird. "Physics Meta Stack Exchange" probably should be "Physics Stack Exchange Meta" or "Physics Meta".